# FourSquare API parameters sw and ne

Tags: api, geolocation, foursquare

If I make this request:
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ne=39.998,-0.06&sw=39.9935,-0.075&intent=browse&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET

I found a result that not is inside the boundingbox that I request:

```
id": "4ea309fa77c8d0ce5e34951a",
"lat": 39.999007638806724,
"lng": -0.0725757901436784,
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to make sure all results in the bounding box are included, sometimes you will see some results that are outside the bounding box, near the borders. If you want to ensure that you do not see any results outside those coordinates, you can filter out such venues.